# How do you bootstrap an Angular2 submodule out of an angular 2 cli bundle?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Background: We are using angular cli to create a UI component library. I am thinking this is not a good fit for CLI as it seems more designed for producing an application. So we are trying to make this library so we can load it into other Angular2 apps and use it as a default toolbox, also so we can use it in legacy non-angular apps. This is a media players library that presently contains an audio player component and will contain a video player and other players.

Specific Problem: I am trying to use the library (main.bundle.js) inside a non-angular.js app. The main.bundle.js bootstraps the entire application. "AppModule." There is a sub-module or AppModule that is being exported that is called "PlayersModule" this contains all the players. I want to be able to load just the PlayerModule into this app and use the  component within that module (also exported).  I am not sure how to take a blank html page and bootstrap just the PlayersModule out of the webpack bundle and have the html page only us the audio-player directive. When I try I get errors about not including the  for the AppComponent Module. However I am not wanting to load that.

Does anyone have some insights on how to do this? Am I over reaching with the angularcli tool to make this happen?